# Shiny-Server app running through reverse proxy unresponsive outside local network

Tags: r, shiny, reverse-proxy, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I have been trying to set up a shiny-server running through a proxy so that I can secure the app through SSL (https). To do this I have the following set up:

- The Host Server is Windows Server 2016 running HyperV and IIS
- I have an instance of Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 running as a VM on HyperV
- I am running the open-source version of Shiny-Server on the Ubuntu VM

Basically in IIS on my Windows Server I have a website set up to route incoming https requests to the Shiny-Server. This works great when connecting to the app from my Windows Server, everything acts as expected, even when connecting with the https domain name.

However, when I connect from outside the local network, the app *loads* but is totally unresponsive. I am using the package [shinyauthr](https://github.com/PaulC91/shinyauthr) to provide a very simple login to the app, and the whole login process works fine when opening the website from the Windows Server, but when I click login when opening the app from outside the network nothing happens. What's weird is that the `withProgress()` loader still appears? Also, the app never greys out, it just repeatedly blinks "Attempting to Reconnect" for a fraction of a second. See the below screenshots:

[Login Page Showing Progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHGfo.png)
[Login Page Showing Attempting to Reconnect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1XTp.png)

My Shiny-Server config is below:

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;
app_init_timeout 600;
app_idle_timeout 0;
sanitize_errors off;
disable_protocols xdr-streaming xhr-streaming iframe-eventsource iframe-htmlfile;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 3838;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you check your IIS logs for missed redirects? For instance, perhaps if a JS library was not found or blocked for some reason, I can see some of `shiny` being less- or un-responsive. (Or for that matter, anything in your `shiny-server` logs that indicate malformed requests?)

Comment: Thanks @r2evans, I looked at both these logs and found nothing was wrong, and it helped me find the issue with the other site :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, it was slightly embarrassing...

I had another old website running on the same Windows Server that was trying to use the same port, so it was competing with the shiny server for traffic. After assigning a new port to the old website everything worked perfectly :)